# Office calc - conditional formatting for weekends

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

Programming a calendar, want to highlight all weekend days by conditional formatting. The value of the cell is the date do be controlled.

There is a Condition called `Formula is` and according to the [help](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Calc/Conditional_Formatting) you can use any formula. So I could write for every day of the year a own formula. In visual basic there is something like "activeCell" or so, which is referencing the active cell. This would make one formula for all.

```
// pseudo code for conditional formatting "Formula is"
IF(WEEKDAY(activeCell)=6 or WEEKDAY(activeCell)=7); TRUE();FALSE())
```

**Is there something like a activeCell or a total other way to archive this simple looking task?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=NOT(OR(WEEKDAY(A1;2)=6;WEEKDAY(A1;2)=7))
```

[image: Conditional formating to mark only weekdays in Excel]

A1 is the cell holding your date. `WEEKDAY` with the second parameter being `2` delivers the number of the weekday with Monday being `1` and Sunday being `7`.

The formula results to `TRUE` if the day is neither a Saturday or a Sunday.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This part I got, but I assume, I've to write this expression for every cell once again? Or have you used this magical cross in the lower right to pull down the formula and it worked?

Comment: No magic here :-). You mark the whole range and type this formula for the top left cell of the range you want to apply it on and Excel will automatically adapt the formula for the rest. So if you reference `A1` in the first row, Excel knows that you want to reference `A2` in the second row. If you do not want this automatism, you might right `A$1` - then Excel will know that it always should reference the first row.

Comment: ...this was to obvious.

Comment: Good to hear that it helped :-)